# How to access header file declaration without #include

Tags: ios, objective-c, header

I have an iOS project-ProjectX (not created by me) which is able to access declaration from a .h file without using #include "someHeader.h".

In ProjectX, I could just create an empty File and refer to a declaration in "someHeader.h", which I find perplexing. Example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@implementation Empty:NSObject
SOME_TYPE_FROM_SOME_HEADER_H x;
@end
```

and the compiler automatically knows where the definition is?!

I have since tried to create an identical project, duplicating all the project settings, adding static libraries/files, etc. but to no avail.

Any ideas on what I might have missed out or what do I need to configure in the project to achieve this?

Comment: I think all those headers are imported in `.pch` file. That's the prefix header file. Search that file in your project.

Comment: @Rishab Hey, you were right! Was not aware precompiled header in the project. Post it as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: It's all right.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Rishab, I was missing a precompiled header (.pch) file. In the project, a pch imported a static library which contained the header file. Therefore, I was able to call the definitions directly.